# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, google-api, android-gradle-plugin

This is the gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cogintus"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jni'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev120-1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

When I debug the project , this error is always appearing :

[image]

Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' 
I searched for the error, and I found that there may be redundant compiles in the dependencies.
But I tried to remove some and no result , please if you know how to solve this or you know exactly what to remove help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` instead `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

When duplicate library presents in your projects then showing this error,So finally

```
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev120-1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Comment: did you gradle your project (after clean and rebuild)

Comment: remove compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

Comment: whats your classpath ?

Comment: removed it but same error,
The class path : package com.google.android.apps.watchme;

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to compile the Play Services library twice. Delete one of these lines :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

**EDIT**

You also have to remove this line

```
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

Add be sure you've had this line in project's gradle :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

Everything is here : https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app

Comment: I did that , and the same error appears : 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project ? Also, sync your project with gadle.

Comment: cleaned,rebuild and synchronized, but nothing new

Comment: Hum, it's strange... Try to go in File -> Invalidate caches / Restart -> Just Restart and build your app again.

Comment: Maybe it's your google-services library... I think you don't have to compile it if you've had it in your gradle top-level. https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app